# How to convert image into emguCV image

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, emgucv

How can I convert an image from the form to an emguCV image?

```
Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image); // error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [constructor](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.4.1/document/html/791fbe59-17c0-26e7-efa7-a1d1ad146ac4.htm) of the `Image` class:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image));
```